# Quantal Repositories have been removed?

Tags: 12.10, mirrors

Every single mirror is missing the Quantal dists.

NOTICE:  Before you comment, I do realize 12.10 is in End of Life status!

But to totally restrict further usage?  Unacceptable!

Comment: Restrict further installations. You should be able to use your system and install apps manually.

Comment: Found this...

On AskUbuntu there is this question which may of help

The repositories for EOL Ubuntu releases are archived, so http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ was moved to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ (raring-updates is here) - basically all you should need to do is replace archive.ubuntu.com & security.ubuntu.com in the software sources with old-releases.ubuntu.com, then run sudo apt-get update.
shareimprove this answer

Comment: What do you think "eol" or end of life means? 12.10 is no longer supported, you can use an old repo, see the link I gave you, but you do so at your own risk. There will be no updates , security or otherwise. ranting about the situation will now win you much support.